# asp calender database c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I'm creating a barbering shop booking system similar to [this](http://www.barbershop.co.uk/book-online/) where the user picks the date from a calender and it opens up available time slots for desired barber. When the date is selected a drop down menu is shown and it gives available barbers on that day, further clicking the barber you want will show the time slots available.

I'm creating a website from ASP.net using C# i have looked at the full calender model and it doesn't fit my purpose. I'm using a basic calendar, data is stored into a database and can be amended with admin privileges. Any ideas how i would do this and what database tables i would need to make this system?

Thanks,

Comment: Hrmm, doesn't seem like you've thought about the design that much. Probably should get on that, then see where you actually have problems.

Comment: okay ive made the design and i have put the calender on the web page how do i think the calender to the barber time slots? create a data source?